# Recognise different flavours of aroma sticks in chinese

Tags: character-identification

Hello I have two photos of aroma sticks (I have numbered them all from 1 to 9 on pictures).
And I have written names of this aroma sticks:
养生艾草香【20克】
药沉养生香【20克】
老山檀香【20克]
檀香【20克】
沉香【20克】
陈化崖柏【20克】
澳洲檀香【20克】
星洲水沉【20克】
乌沉香【20克】
伊利安沉香【20克】

And I want to make a relation (numbers to chinese names of this flavours)
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try Google Translate? That'd be a good place to start.

Comment: Yes, Sir I know how to use google translate. 

Unfortunately this doesn't help me with understanding what is written on pictures and what the thing "Health wormwood fragrance" for example is. 

So not sure if your comment is really useful  (unfortunately)

Answer (score 1):

1. 老山檀香
2. 沉香
3. 陈化崖柏
4. 澳洲檀香
5. **药沉养生香**
6. 檀香
7. **药沉养生香**
8. 老山檀香
9. 养生艾草香

Comment: thanks. noticed that 1st and 8 are the same and 5 & 7 are the same too

Comment: I missed 1 & 8. But now you can google to get the meaning of each label.